# Cocos2d. Mistake in adding new classes

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am new in cocos2d, just make my first project. But after adding new classes I've got this mistakes and can't understand where is the problem. And I've already changed CMakeLists.txt

```
home/anna/dragon_game_v1/dragon/Classes/Player.h:12:1: error: 'USING_NS_CC' does not name a type USING_NS_CC;

warning: 'cocos2d::kCCPrioritySystem' defined but not used [-unused-variable];

make[2]: ***[cocos22d/cocos/CMakeFiles/cocos2d.dir/__/__/Classes/Player.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [cocos22d/cocos/CMakeFiles/cocos2d.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Thanks to everyone

Comment: cocos2d or cocos2d-x??

Comment: cocos2d-x-3.4 in fact

Comment: Show us code. maybe you miss to `#include <cocos2d.h>` ?